# Using new Graph API to pass a var from PHP to .swf file - Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook

I am using this in my .php file and I want to pass the user's photo variable into a .swf file.

```
<?php 
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
 'cookie' => true,
 ));
$me = null;

if ($session) {
 try {  
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
$me =  $facebook->api('/me');       

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   error_log($e);
  }
}
?>
 <fb:swf swfsrc='http://www.aaaa.com/facebook_application/Main.swf?photo=<?= uid ?>'           allowscriptaccess='always' flashvars='' 
swfbgcolor='#cccccc' wmode='transparent'  flashvars=''    width='500' height='400'/>
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens? WHat does this look like in the browser's "view source" view?

Comment: i get this error from my debugger browser
`Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2036: Load Never Completed. URL: https://graph.facebook.com/undefined/picture`

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP to include the photo URI into flashvars.

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? I m not so advanced with PHP